# tvOS - how to go back to home screen programmatically

Tags: tvos, uitapgesturerecognizer

On the main screen of my tvOS app, I am using a UITapGestureRecognizer to watch for the Menu button being pressed. Depending on what's on-screen, I need to handle it in different ways, but obviously, in some cases, I want to interpret that Menu press as "exit to the home screen." I can't find an API which will do this cleanly. `exit(0)` is as close as I can find, and it feels like a crash--the app disappears abruptly with no transition effect. Is there an API I can use? Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(consumeTap:)];
    tapGestureRec.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypeMenu)];
    [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRec];
}

- (void)handleTap:(id)_
{
    if (ShouldExitNow()) exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, I can do this by programmatically removing the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the view whenever I want MENU to go home, and re-adding it when I want to catch it again. Super clumsy, but it works great now.

Answer (score 4):

You could setup a `Bool` and check it in your `handleTap` function to return to the home screen:

```
if returnToHomeScreen {
    UIControl().sendAction(#selector(NSURLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.sharedApplication(), forEvent: nil)
}
```

Comment: NSURLSessionTask.suspend? That API isn't meant for going to the home screen at all... it might work by chance but I'm pretty sure it's not intended functionality.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I agree, but there doesn't seem to be any *clean* way to achieve this. Better than using `exit(0)` at least.

Comment: Well, I found and posted a solution that works perfectly without relying on undocumented API. You have to juggle adding/removing a handler but it's all within the documented API. A trick like this is liable to get your app pulled.

Answer (score 0):

You can set delegate for your UITapGestureRecognizer and implement following method of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive press: UIPress) -> Bool {
    // return false to skip your handling of this menu button press
    // (and perform default "go to home" system action)
    // or return true to handle it by yourself
}
```